# Pyranose v/s Furanose form of Glucose and Fructose

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbohydrates

According to my textbook (Class 12 NCERT Chemistry):

> Fructose also exists in two cyclic forms which are obtained
> by the addition of —OH at C5 to the C = O group. The ring, thus formed
> is a five membered ring and is named as furanose with analogy to the
> compound furan.

I understood why the pyranose structure for glucose is more stable than the furanose structure ( The pyranose form has the perfect 60° dihedral angle between two non-ring atoms which minimises this type of strain Source: [Stability of furanose vs. pyranose form of glucose?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38286/stability-of-furanose-vs-pyranose-form-of-glucose)). But I do not understand why the same cannot be applied to the fructose structure.

So, to summarize : **Why is fructose present in furanose form and not in pyranose form?**

Comment: Actually the pyranose form of fructose is favored at equilibrium in water. . .

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22547/

Comment: @Andrew is correct about the pyranose form of fructose. http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/carbohydrates44.pdf That fructose in sucrose is a furanoside is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the same reasoning can be applied to fructose, and, as with glucose, the beta-pyranose form is most stable.

It is common in biochemistry textbooks, however, to draw fructose as a furanose. The reason for this is that fructose 6-phosphate is a common metabolite, and the phosphate group prevents the 6'-hydroxyl group from participating in ring closure. As a result, the free 5'-hydroxyl attacks the carbonyl, and a furanose is formed. Similarly, fructan biopolymers often contain 1,6 linkages that also prevent the pyranose formation.